# Invoking a shell script when modification of file happens in a directory

Tags: linux, shell, batch-processing, linux-mint

I am organizing a movie library when many users update movie files and then I manually update a Database using a PHP script so that from the URL user can know the list of movie residing in the library.

I know I can make an entry to Crontab in Linux so that in every 10 hour it run the PHP script to update the database however I wanted to know is there a way in which PHP file can be run automatically when user paste a movie file to the database kind of notifier which will invoke the php so the database can be updated in real time?

I am using Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) which is an inotify based crontab.

For instance, here is a sample you can use with `incrontab -e`:

```
/home/moviedb/download IN_CLOSE_WRITE /home/moviedb/classify-script.php $#
```

which will hook on the `/home/moviedb/download` folder for any finished download (closed file) and run the classify-script.php with the event related filename.

Comment: Thanx Aif for quick response. Does that notify you about the modification you do to a directory with event type?

Comment: @saty you indeed have events see `man 5 incrontab` : moved_to, moved_from, close_write, close_nonwrite, open, create, delete etc ..